# Probability of each boy standing diametrically opposite to a girl in a round table

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

There are 9 girls and 5 boys (all 14 of them are unique) are standing next to each other forming a circle with random placement.

If the probability of each boys are standing directly opposite to girl can be written as $\frac{m}{n}$ where $GCD(m,n)=1$ and $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$ find $m+n$.

Here is my attempt: Take 5 girls that will stand directly opposite to each boys, and assume that this girl and the boy opposite to her as one object hence in total we have 5 element to be placed around circle with 9 place thus making it ${9 \choose 5}   \times 4!$ ways. However, the place of the girl and opposite boy can be interchanged thus making it $32$ways.Since we are choosing 5 girls from 9 then there are ${9}\choose{5}$ ways. Finally place the other 4 girls thus we have $4!$ ways. Thus the probability is $$P=\frac{{9\choose5}\times 4! \times {9\choose5} \times 32}{13!}$$ in which upon simplifying I got $m+n>>191$.

However it is clearly wrong as key answer is $191$. In which step is it wrong? What is the right approach to this problem?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "exactly one" girl.  Each person is directly opposite a single other person, right?  $\#1$ is opposite $\#8$ and so on.  So you are just asking for the probability that each boy is opposite a girl, or have I misunderstood?

Comment: @lulu yes you understand it right. I'll edit the question

Comment: Is "directly opposite" used as synonym for "diametrically opposite"? Or are you referring to a particular axis of symmetry of the circle?

Comment: @Stef    Yes you you can see it as diametrically opposite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note:  the individuals don't matter here, just their genders.  So it's as if we had $9$ white balls and $5$ black balls that we were putting into $14$ positions around a table.

Assume that the positions are numbered $1$ through $14$.  Now, there are exactly $7$ pairs of diametrically opposed positions.  A "good" arrangement requires that we choose $5$ of the pairs to put the boys into, $\binom 75$ ways to choose such, and then for each of those pairs we choose whether the boy goes in the low or the higher numbered position, $2^5$ ways to do that.  thus there are exactly $\binom 75\times 2^5$ good arrangements.  Of course, there are $\binom {14}5$ arrangements in total, so the answer is $$\binom 75\times 2^5\Big /\binom {14}5=\frac {48}{143}$$

which confirms the official result.

Comment: Shouldn't the total arrangement be 13! Because we're arranging 14 elements in a circle?

Comment: I have fixed the $14$ positions.  An arrangement is determined by the location of the boys.  As I said, the individual populations are irrelevant.  If you prefer, you can multiply numerator and denominator by $14!$, or by $13!$ if you have decided to identify rotated arrangements.  Of course, that factor cancels out.

Comment: @user1259172 so long as you are consistent with your numerator and denominator in probability, it doesn't matter.  We can choose to remember which direction on the table is "north" or we can ignore it.  So long as our numerator either also remembers which direction is "north" or not to match how our denominator acted.

Comment: "identical", but yes.  As I say, that's not important.  It just saves us having to track a bunch of irrelevant factors that are sure to cancel out.  Here, it just means multiplying numerator and denominator by $5!\times 9!$.  Note:  I said $14!$ before but that's wrong, as we do need to keep track of gender.  It should have been $5!\times 9!$.

Comment: @user1259172 Your comment-question following this answer is a good question, which was well answered by subsequent comments.  However, the answer(s) given to your comment-question might require experience to comprehend.  You can *alternatively verify* that lulu's numerical answer is accurate by using lulu's analysis as a guide, and applying the entire analysis (numerator and denominator) to a circle, rather than a row.